# How to get the log file of an OMNeT++ simulation

Tags: dataset, omnet++

Is there any way to get automatically the content of the log view in OMNeT++ presented below into a file (any type, even in a text file)?

[image]

Note that I am not talking about the `.elog` file generated automatically by OMNET++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to automatically write the content of Log Viewer in Message mode.

Comment: So the only solution is to copy and paste it ?

Comment: Yes, you may only copy/paste.